# Law of Conservation of Time?

Tags: conservation-laws, time-travel

**So, it may or may not seem to be stupid,** but if we think that there is a person named John who travels back in time by any means, and he met his past lets say him small John then the past small John will grow into John and he will too meet his past and it just creates a loop here and it will go for forever, even if universe get ended, then isn’t time conserved here?

Comment: What do you mean by "Conservation of time"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_law There is no known law for conservation of time.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_paradox

Answer (score 2):

> met his past lets say him small John then the past small John will grow into John and he will too meet his past and it just creates a loop here

This is one of the many contradictions that result from time travel. Some have hypothesised that there could be infinitely many realities existing in infinitely many universes/timelines. It could be explained by considering that if you traveled back in time and met your younger self, you're not going back to your own history, but a copy of your history, and everything you do in this version of your history will affect the alternate future of that universe and not your own.

> even if universe get ended, then isn’t time conserved here?

I’m not sure I understand what you mean by “time conserved” and there is no theory (that I’m aware of) where time is “conserved”. There does not seem to be any physical significance in such an idea  and therefore it need not have a conservation property. There are physical quantities that do not evolve over time or are conserved. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Actually there is no law of conservation of Time. I was proposing the law and wanted to check that if my imagination is correct or not.

Comment: Any suggestions @Dr jh

Comment: As to what? Asking if time is conserved is not a meaningful question. Explain what you’re asking and I will try to help you.

Comment: Sir I am just a teen of 14 and I don't know if i can explain it correctly. So, one day I just imagined that due to the infinte loop wouldnt in that infinite loop of time time get conserved. Hope this will help.

Comment: If you are asking if within that “loop” it will continue to repeat infinitely so that the only “time that will pass” within that loop is the man goes to the past at say age 30, meets himself at age 10 and then he grows and then goes back and meets himself over and over so that the only time that passes is 20 years then 20 years...forever so that the age of his “universe” is only 20 years and therefore time is conserved? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, Yes. That's what I asked.

Comment: So, is that law of conservation of time, correct or not, Sir.

Comment: I would have to say yes if that is the interpretation. You are very philosophical for someone your age and that is excellent. Well done and good luck with your studies.

Comment: Thanks, Sir. If I got another question like that, Can i ask you please? Because only 2 people on this Earth understand me and you are the second one and First one is Dr. Shariff

Comment: If you post any other questions do it the same way you posted this question. If I don't see it, just leave a comment here and I'll try to answer it.

Comment: Ok @Dr jh . Would be doing the same

Comment: I have a question and [this is the link to question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/597731/grandfather-paradox-is-wrong)

Comment: Any answer @Dr jh , about this

Answer (score 1):

@Krrish Dhaneja When one considers what special relativity says about spacetime, one realizes that the proposal of time conservation may be understood on the same footing as the proposal of conservation of position: if some system experienced conservation of position, then the act of moving one particle to a positive position would exert a non-local force to move some other particle to an equal-in-magnitude, but opposite in sign position. This requires action-at-a-distance which has historically been looked down upon. As such, one would expect that conservation of time would also require action-at-a-distance. While systems that demonstrate such non-local effects are now being looked at with renewed vigor (e.g., entanglement), it seems unlikely that such a principle would, if proposed, be accepted in the near future.

Comment: Please please explain me in simple wording. Please....

Comment: please explain me. @PrawwarP

Comment: SR indicates that space and time be treated symmetrically. As such, if we treat ct as a distance, then one may argue that if time were conserved, space (position) would also be conserved and vice versa. So, let us start by considering conservation of position: say you move one particle in a 2 particle system experiencing position conservation. Then, by position conservation, the 2nd particle must move in the opposite direction. This would mean that you could move 2 particles by moving 1 particle (where the particles are not in contact with each other). That means action at a distance.